Excel - Create IF Function from results of a multiple criteria XLOOKUP

Hello,
I currently have the following:
=XLOOKUP(1,(A2:A10=E3)*(b2:b10=E4),C2:C10)
So, if 103 and First Aider match, it returns a Yes, because that is what is in column C.  If it doesn’t match, it returns ‘#N/A’.
I want to find a way that if E3 and E4 match, then it returns ‘Yes’, but if one or both don’t match, it returns ‘No’.   Essentially some kind of IF Function of getting rid of column C and any resulting ‘#N/A’
Thanks

The Fourth argument of XLOOKUP is there for you to fill in when nothing is found.

Try =IF(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(1,(A2:A10=E3)*(B2:B10=E4))),"Yes","No") or =IF(SUM(TOCOL((A2:A10=E3)*(B2:B10=E4),2)),"Yes","No").

=IF(OR/SUM((A1:A10=E3)*(B1:B10=E4)),"Yes","No")?

You can use this formula
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((A2:A10=E3)*(B2:B10=E4)),"yes","no")
which is independant of column C
If both conditions are true then SUMPRODUCT returns true which is evaluated by the IF-clause

You can use the IFNA function:
=IFNA(XLOOKUP(1,(A2:A10=E3)*(b2:b10=E4),C2:C10),"No")

Or, easier:
=XLOOKUP(1,(A2:A10=E3)*(b2:b10=E4),C2:C10,"No")


Match Two Columns
Static
From the Comments: Cell Sheet1!E5 (Result)

You could use one of the following formulas:
=IF(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(1,(A2:A10=E3)*(B2:B10=E4))),"Yes","No")
=IF(SUM(TOCOL((A2:A10=E3)*(B2:B10=E4),2)),"Yes","No")



Dynamic

To make it dynamic, you could do the following.


Sheet Sheet1

Convert the data to an Excel table (Ctrl+T).

Sheet Hidden

Add a new sheet and rename it e.g. to Hidden.

Cell Hidden!A3
=SORT(UNIQUE(TOCOL(Table1[Person],3)))


Cell Hidden!B3
=SORT(UNIQUE(TOCOL(Table1[Job],3)))



Data Validation

Cell Sheet1!E3 (List)
=Hidden!A3#


Cell Sheet1!E4 (List)
=Hidden!B3#



Cell Sheet1!E5 (Result)

Excel 2021
=IF(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(1,(Table1[Person]=E3)*(Table1[Job]=E4))),"Yes","No")


MS365
=IF(SUM(TOCOL((Table1[Person]=E3)*(Table1[Job]=E4),2)),"Yes","No")



Hide

Now hide the Hidden sheet or use the VeryHidden feature.
To utilize the latter, press F11 to open the Visual Basic Editor. Open the Project Explorer Ctrl+R and the Properties window F4. In the Project Explorer, locate the Hidden tab e.g. Sheet2(Hidden) and click on it. In the Properties window, under Name, check that the correct tab is selected. If so, under Visible select 2 - xlSheetVeryHidden.
Exit the Visual Basic Editor.
Memorize or write down these steps to unhide the sheet when necessary.

